# convert .mp3 to .ogg opus / telegram bot / node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, telegram, telegram-bot

I need a way that converts audio messages to voice messages in a telegram bot.
 can you please suggest me a way to do that in nodeJS. 
If you can suggest me a way that can converts .MP3 files to .OGG files in a simple script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilise ffmpeg. Simply find a NodeJS wrapper for this command line utility.

After you have that, you can run an ffmpeg command such as `ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -c:a libvorbis -q:a 4 output.ogg` to convert your input to your desired output format.

I'd recommend trying https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg

Comment: This could be a good way. but unfortunately I need a light library for this project, I have a limited server. 
Do you have any idea?

Comment: You could perhaps set up a secondary server or even a serverless function to run the conversion (depending on how long it takes/resource intensity) and sends the file back? I've looked at alternative libraries for the conversion and they don't see all that promising.